# Angular methods (constants, config, run, factory, service), Does it matter what order you call them?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application built on [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) and it does a great job of allowing all my angular components to live in their own separate files.

I was just running all my code through JSLint and it asked to remove `'use strict';` from my **index.module.js** file as it worked out that this was the global or starting file for my entire application.

I was reviewing the JSLint warning here [use-the-function-form-of-use-strict](https://jslinterrors.com/use-the-function-form-of-use-strict)

This got me thinking, how did JSLint know that **index.module.js** was the starting code block.

Which then got me thinking, does it matter what order angular startup methods are called.

**Can these methods be run in any order you like, or is there an expected sequential order for these calls?**

```
angular.module('appName')
angular.module('appName').run(function() { });
angular.module('appName').config(function() { });
angular.module('appName').service(function() { });
angular.module('appName').constant('blah', 'blah');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - no it's not.

The way angular is doing it - is when the page renders and scripts are loaded it register all the components(services\config\constants..) but do not execute them.
When the registration completes angular is starting to execute the application, providers --> config --> run and so on..
If your interested in some more detailed explanation on the way angular works under the hood you can check out this [awesome article](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/03/09/build-learn-your-own-light-lightweight-angularjs).

*forgot to mention that you must define your module first.